# jQueryUI nested accordion only working on first sub-list

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm working on a site that has a dynamically generated FAQ and I'm trying to get nested accordions working.  The problem is, only the first collection of questions take on the ui-accordion class.

Here's my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/SmFdt/

(I just copied the source of the page and stripped out most of the text)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are all the `<div>` tags and verbose class names necessary perhaps use some `<ul><li>` elements, give the code a spruce up then look at it again.

Comment: You should post your code here instead of relying on jsfiddle.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You've got the same id assigned to multiple divs.  Try the following instead:

**HTML**

```
<h1>Frequently Asked Questions</h1>

<div id="faqs-container" class="accordian">
    <h3><a href="#">One</a></h3>
    <div class="accordian">
        <h3><a href="#">A</a></h3>
        <div>AAAAAAAAAA</div>
        <h3><a href="#">B</a></h3>
        <div>BBBBBBBBBB</div>
    </div>
    <h3><a href="#">Two</a></h3>
    <div class="accordian">
        <h3><a href="#">A2</a></h3>
        <div>AAAAAAAAAA2</div>
        <h3><a href="#">B2</a></h3>
        <div>BBBBBBBBBB2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("div.accordian").accordion({
    autoHeight: false,
    collapsible: true,
    active: false
});
```

Link to example: http://jsfiddle.net/SmFdt/1/

Comment: Thanks.  I had such a mess, I didn't realize the IDs were screwing things up.

Comment: This was a rare scenario and this page is the only page that has the answer.

Comment: What does `autoHeight: false` do, is it like `heightStyle: "content"`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/SmFdt/3/

The reason it was not working was you were using the same id for multiple divs. I have changed the ids to classes.

On a side note, you have lot of code to display the accordion. You may possibly want to consider reducing some code. (e.g. no need of `<p>` inside `<div>`. You can control the spacing using CSS margin and padding properties.)

Comment: The paragraph tag inside the div makes a lot more sense (although still ridiculous) if you see the finished product.  All the Q's and A's are coming from a database that was generated by a user, using a tinyMCE form. Both you and Phil were right...I just need to do some house-keeping in this app.

Comment: This one seems to have more styling:
http://jsfiddle.net/xanetia/8kz4m (Personally I ended up preferring a tree view)